# BigInteger Factorial Table 1-30

Tags: java, biginteger, factorial

I'm supposed to print a table of the integers from 0 to 30 along with their factorials. I tried, but I keep getting an error saying BigInteger(long) has private access in BigInteger? Thoughts?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 0;
    for (x = 0; x < 31;) {
        System.out.println(x + " " + factorial(x));

        x = x + 1;

    }
}

/*
       public static int factorial (int n) {   
       if (n == 0) {
             return 1;
        } else {
            return n * factorial (n-1);
           }
        }
         // error occuring at 13! could be because the number becomes too great for int to handle, resulting in an overflow error.

     }*/
public static BigInteger factorial(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    } else {

        BigInteger result = new BigInteger(n).multiply(factorial(n - 1));(error here)

        return result;
    }
    //return new BigInteger(n) * factorial(n - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `BigInteger` constructor taking a `long`, but it is `private` so can only be called from the `BigInteger` class itself.

You need to use `BigInteger.valueOf(n)` instead.

Comment: took out the new and added your suggestion and it works! Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem.. Glad I could help.